# Is a complex determinant still a "volume"?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

I like the interpretation of the determinant of an $m\times n$ matrix as the volume of the $n$-dimensional parallelepiped whose sides are the columns of the matrix.

Does this interpretation hold also for a complex matrix? If so what's the meaning of a complex volume?

Comment: In the real $1\times 1$ case, the determinant volume becomes (signed) length. Does that make sense when expanded to complex numbers to you?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I'm asking you to try figuring out the $1\times 1$ case before trying the general $n\times n$ case. If you can't get  the $1\times 1$ case to work, there is not much hope for the general case. Also note that I don't know the answer, I'm just telling you where you should start.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, I don't know either! Does it make sense to think of two separate contributions? Like, a real volume and an imaginary one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are complex determinants for matrices possible and if so, how can they be interpreted?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140314/are-complex-determinants-for-matrices-possible-and-if-so-how-can-they-be-interp)